# What's the common way to check if a field is null or undefined (but not zero or empty string) in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I know I can't do `if (!obj.x)` because if `obj.x` is `0` or `""`, it will be "truthy".

Option 1: I could do `if (obj.x === null || obj.x === undefined)`.

Option 2: But could I just do `if (obj.x == null)`?

Just to be clear, I want a condition that is true when `obj.x` is `null` or `undefined`, but false for any other value.

According to the comments, both options are equivalent but option 2 is more clear. I agree.

EDIT:

Someone pointed out that there are similar questions (see links above), but in this case I was thinking of fields, rather than variables. The difference is that fields can be `undefined` and there is no runtime error when using them. I updated my question accordingly.

EDIT 2:

This question was closed because there are similar questions. I think there is a slight difference here, because in my question I'm checking a field/property of an object, not a variable, so the `typeof` operator is not needed.

Comment: Yes, those two are exactly equivalent.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it. Better not to rely on `==`, using `===` makes the code a *lot* more intuitive to read - using two separate `===` tests is probably the better way to go

Comment: This question isn't asking anything that isn't already addressed by the canonical question. The only difference is that when checking a standalone variable, you need to use `typeof` *if* the variable might not have been declared yet.

Comment: `!= null` and `== null` is a common shortcut for checking undefined & null. Otherwise you should use `===` and `!==` respectively.

Comment: “Actually, it doesn't make sense to check `variable === undefined` since it would throw an error when the variable is undefined” is incorrect – `undefined` is a value, like `null`, and variables can have it. It’s much rarer to not know whether a variable has been declared.

Comment: Thanks Ry, you're right. I removed that sentence.